# Windows script to run at shutdown

Tags: windows, powershell, shutdown

i have been trying to get a windows startup/shutdown sound to play, i couldn't get the sounds to play so i asked on Microsoft, here is the link https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/cannot-change-windows-start-up-sound/8bbcb0a0-1402-4f1e-b080-9c8d526bc205
and i was told that its not possible. well too bad because i am not going to stop there, so i went to local group policy editor on windows 10 where you can choose scripts to run during shutdown and start up. i then wrote a very small PowerShell command with the file name of "shutdown.ps1" the code inside of shutdown.ps1 is
`start "C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown\TADA.wav"`
this file is located in the C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown directory along with the TADA.wav file that it plays when it shuts down.

**now the issue i am having is that when windows is shutting down, its ending all processes so it *does not*  play the sound.** what can i do to change that?
I'm pretty new to all of this and am very grateful for any input you can give.
thanks in advance,
Devin

Comment: @RemyLebeau  https://imgur.com/gallery/ZV3mwnd i have it enabled here and it doesn't work, i also enabled it in registry and turned off fast boot. still doesn't work.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i just tried the registry changes and the option for logoff isn't showing up still, weird

Comment: and this "independent advisor" on Microsoft is saying that windows 10 no longer supports it and that no online solutions work, this is what he said "Hi devinshroff1

Windows10 does not support a shutdown sound like previous versions of Windows, you wil find many methods posted online, sadly, none of them work."

Answer (score 1):

From [How to Change the Windows 10 Logoff, Logon, and Shutdown Sounds in Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/274010/how-to-change-the-windows-10-logoff-logon-and-shutdown-sounds-in-windows-10/):

> ...
>
> While you can still customize what sounds sounds play for most OS events, Windows 10 hid shut down, logoff, and logon from view. They’re still around, though. You just need to make a few mild changes in the Windows Registry to get them back.
>
> ### Add the Actions Back to the Sound Control Panel by Editing the Registry
>
> To add the shutdown, logoff, and logon actions back to the menu in the Sound Control Panel app, you just need to make a few little tweaks in the Windows Registry.
>
> ...
>
> - Open the Registry Editor by hitting Start and typing “regedit.” Press Enter to open Registry Editor and then give it permission to make changes to your PC.
> - In the Registry Editor, use the left sidebar to navigate to the following key:
>
>   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\EventLabels`
> - You’re going to be making one small change in each of three different subkeys inside that `EventLabels` key. First, we’ll tackle the shutdown sound or, as Windows likes to call it, System Exit. Under the `EventLabels` key on the left side of Registry Editor, select the `SystemExit` subkey. On the right side, double-click the `ExcludeFromCPL` value.
> - Note that by default, the value is 1, meaning that the action is excluded from the Control Panel. Change the value to 0 and then click “OK.”
> - Next, you’re going to make exactly the same change in two other subkeys inside the `EventLabels` key: `WindowsLogoff` and `WindowsLogon`. Head into each of those folders, open the `ExcludeFromCPL` value inside, and change the value from 1 to 0.
> - No need to restart Windows. You can go ahead and test your changes right away. Open up the Sound Control Panel app by right-clicking the speaker icon in your Notification Area and selecting “Sounds.” <sup>1</sup>
> - You should now see the new actions (Exit Windows, Windows Logoff, and Windows Logon) available in the selection window and you can assign whatever sounds you like to those actions.
> - If, for whatever reason, you want to hide those actions from the Control Panel again, just head back into Registry Editor and change each of those ExcludeFromCPL values back to 1.

<sup>1: On my machine, to get to the Sounds control panel, I had to go into the Settings, choose "Personalization", then "Themes", then `Sounds".</sup>

**UPDATE:**

And indeed, all three sound events show up in my Sounds control panel once I re-enable them in the Registry.  However, I tried assigning audio files to them, and although Windows remembered the assignments, nothing played when invoking those actions.

So, I guess the playback functionality is simply not implemented for those events anymore.  This seems to be confirmed in your discussion with a Microsoft Insider on answers.microsoft.com (with an 89% upvote rate of 143K replies, I would think he knows what he's talking about):

> In Windows 10 **there is no way to change the Windows Startup Sound**, that sound is set permanently in a DLL in Windows, it is not an audio file like the other system sounds, and even when you turn on the Startup sound on that dialog, sometimes the startup sound will play and other times it will not, this is a known bug in Windows 10, which seems to have been fixed in Windows 11
>
> **Windows10 does not support a shutdown sound like previous versions of Windows**, you wil find many methods posted online, sadly, none of them work.

Comment: THANK YOU, i had made registry changes to the "windows logon" and "windows logoff" keys before you said this but i didnt change "system exit" like you said above. im trying it now.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 11 work:

```
$PlayWav=New-Object System.Media.SoundPlayer
$PlayWav.SoundLocation='C:\Windows\Media\Windows Logoff Sound.wav'
$PlayWav.playsync()
```

in the .ps1 script. Then, I add the script on Group Policy Management Editor>User Configuration>Windows Settings>Scripts (Logon/Logoff)>Logoff.

I hope this helps.